# Each time I lock screen on Ubuntu 22 all running apps and terminals are killed

Tags: 22.04, lock-screen

I installed Ubuntu 22 on a compact computer.

Every time I lock the computer (Super+L / WIN+L), and enough time passes before I unlock it again (say, after 1 hour) all running applications and open consoles are killed.

As a matter of fact, it feels like the computer was just started instead of unlocked.

This is obviously not good, considering sometimes I had unsaved progress lost.

I looked up on Ask Ubuntu, but can't find this problem discussed. Following some leads on web pages I read, I looked up my power settings, and found nothing wrong with them. To be sure, I set my computer consumption on "Performance" mode, to avoid hinting Ubuntu I might want apps getting killed, but with no improvement.

I'm not proficient with logs and console-based investigations, so unfortunately I'm not sure how to better detail this issue, but I'll gladly follow-up on documenting the problem if I receive good comments on this topic.

I thank you in advance for taking time to help.

**Edit**: as suggested in comments, I provide hereby more information, and I add an important detail which I forgot to mention: the computer has a dual boot with also Windows 10. Windows 10 was only run once, and after that I installed Ubuntu 22 along with Windows 10 (following the wizard installation).

In the installation, I selected "minimal installation" to avoid software like LibreOffice or Firefox which I did not want/need on my system.

Not sure these details matter.

As per requested by the kind users below, my power settings are as follows:

Power mode:

- Performance (problem was the same with Balanced)

Power saving options:

- Screen blank: 15 minutes
- Automatic suspend: Off

Suspend and Power button:

- Button behaviour: Power off

Also as requested, the output of `last` is as follows. The words `down` and `crash` seem to point to a useful direction, but I am no expert to tell:

```
raggot   tty2         tty2             Fri Jul 15 11:07   still logged in
reboot   system boot  5.15.0-41-generi Fri Jul 15 11:04   still running
raggot   tty2         tty2             Thu Jul 14 14:25 - down   (00:21)
reboot   system boot  5.15.0-41-generi Thu Jul 14 12:30 - 14:47  (02:16)
raggot   tty2         tty2             Thu Jul 14 11:05 - crash  (01:25)
reboot   system boot  5.15.0-40-generi Thu Jul 14 11:04 - 14:47  (03:42)
raggot   tty2         tty2             Wed Jul 13 13:40 - down   (01:12)
reboot   system boot  5.15.0-40-generi Wed Jul 13 12:57 - 14:53  (01:55)
raggot   tty2         tty2             Wed Jul 13 10:36 - crash  (02:20)
reboot   system boot  5.15.0-40-generi Wed Jul 13 10:36 - 14:53  (04:17)
raggot   tty2         tty2             Tue Jul 12 15:30 - down   (01:56)
reboot   system boot  5.15.0-40-generi Tue Jul 12 14:29 - 17:27  (02:58)
raggot   tty2         tty2             Tue Jul 12 09:42 - crash  (04:46)
reboot   system boot  5.15.0-40-generi Tue Jul 12 09:39 - 17:27  (07:47)
raggot   tty2         tty2             Thu Jul  7 10:57 - down   (06:11)
reboot   system boot  5.15.0-40-generi Thu Jul  7 10:57 - 17:08  (06:11)
raggot   tty2         tty2             Thu Jul  7 10:49 - down   (00:07)
reboot   system boot  5.15.0-40-generi Thu Jul  7 10:49 - 10:57  (00:07)
```

Output of `uptime` before locking:

```
12:35:36 up  1:31,  1 user,  load average: 0,18, 0,16, 0,13
```

**Edit 2**: I was now next to the machine when the issue occurred. The system did not just unlock. It actually entirely rebooted.

I now ran `journalctl` and captured the following:

```
jul 15 17:10:12 Elitedesk kernel: usb 2-2: USB disconnect, device number 3
jul 15 17:10:12 Elitedesk kernel: FAT-fs (sda1): unable to read boot sector to mark fs as dirty
jul 15 17:10:12 Elitedesk udisksd[629]: Cleaning up mount point /media/raggot/STIL_USB (device 8:1 no longer exists)
jul 15 17:10:12 Elitedesk systemd[1]: media-raggot-STIL_USB.mount: Deactivated successfully.
jul 15 17:10:12 Elitedesk drawio[9924]: Failed to measure available space: Error getting filesystem info for /media/raggot/STIL_USB: No such file or directory
jul 15 17:10:12 Elitedesk drawio[9924]: Failed to measure available space: Error getting filesystem info for /media/raggot/STIL_USB: No such file or directory
jul 15 17:11:30 Elitedesk kernel: snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC0D2: HDMI: pin NID 0x5 not registered
jul 15 17:11:30 Elitedesk update-notifier[3724]: gtk_widget_get_scale_factor: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
jul 15 17:11:30 Elitedesk update-notifier[3724]: gtk_widget_get_scale_factor: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
-- Boot f2ffcd16bc0441cab6449548c9e8a991 --
```

I have 1 screen connected to 2 working stations. Before it crashed, 2 things happened:

1. I removed a USB stick from the "problematic" station
2. I switched the screen (from the screen's UI) from the "problematic" station to the other.

The moment I switched it back to the computer, I saw that it was already in the Grub page to select the OS, and it booted into Ubuntu shortly after.

Any idea what the problem can be, given the log?

**Edit 3:** After the last crash, this afternoon, I ran the following command, on suggestion of a comment below: `sudo journalctl -b -1 -e`.
It returned these logs in the last lines:

```
jul 20 14:30:01 Elitedesk CRON[103211]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
jul 20 14:30:15 Elitedesk update-notifier[2744]: gtk_widget_get_scale_factor: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
jul 20 14:30:15 Elitedesk update-notifier[2744]: gtk_widget_get_scale_factor: assertion 'GTK_IS_WIDGET (widget)' failed
jul 20 14:30:16 Elitedesk kernel: snd_hda_codec_hdmi hdaudioC0D2: HDMI: pin NID 0x5 not registered
```

I believe there is a hardware problem caused by the DisplayPort to HDMI adapter connected behind the computer. This would explain why, when I (seemingly with no importance) turned off the screen or change the screen's input to another port, the crash (sometimes) occurred.

Does this error ring a bell? Any idea how I could solve it?

Comment: Please add the output of `uptime` and `last` and tell us all the Power settings (Power Saving Options, Suspend & Power Button, etc).

Comment: First step is to put a pin in the timestream with `date '+%y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' >pin.tmp`
  
Then, do your screenlock thing. When your system is usable again,
`sudo journalctl  --since="$(cat pin.tmp)"`.
  
This will show you all the log messages since you set `pin.tmp`. The first several messages relate to your problem.

Comment: @WayneVosberg Power options and output of `last` are now edited in. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @waltinator I managed to capture accurately the issue right after it happened, and produced a log using the instructions you provided. Thanks for this!

Comment: 1) how are you unlocking the computer? 2) why remove an apparently mounted and active USB drive? 3) does `sudo journalctl -b -1 -e` give any more detailed info?

Comment: @WayneVosberg, please beware I now understood it's not really "unlocking", but rather beginning a new session, as the computer shut down after locking. So, 1) entering my password at the start screen. 2) It contained data I had to open from another computer. It's just a normal USB flash drive. Other crashes had nothing to do with USBs being removed though. 3) It does, but I'm not sure what to look for. I just created a new "pin" file as per waltinator's suggestion above, and I will update my question with the new outcome when it happens again. Thank you!

Comment: @WayneVosberg I just updated the question a last time. I think thanks to your last suggestion, I finally found the culprit. No idea how to solve it though. If you don't either, I will just open another question, given how much this one has diverged... Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: I think the next thing I would do is google your computer model number and BIOS version and see if there is a known problem with waking up from sleep -- not uncommon with older systems. Also check for a BIOS update.

Comment: @WayneVosberg thank you. If there is any way you could answer my question (or whatever is left of it) I'll be happy to accept it.